# What is the difference between Condition or ConditionVariable?

Tags: android, multithreading, condition-variable

I need to use a condition variable in my code. Looking up the android API, I saw that the package android.os contained [ConditionVariable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ConditionVariable.html). But I also found [Condition](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) under java.util.concurrent.locks.

The two classes seem to be designed for the same purpose.

```
Condition.await()  <-> ConditionVariable.block()
Condition.signal() <-> ConditionVariable.open()
```

Is there a difference I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the docs you linked, `Condition` can wake single Threads, instead of waking all waiting ones (`signal` vs `signalAll`).

`ConditionVariable` is state-based and thus allows keeping the condition open (in contrast to releasing all waiting threads at a single time, it is possible to not block threads at all using `open` and `close`).

---

So you should use `Condition` if

- you need to be compatible to regular Java (for example in a Library used for a PC/Server/whatever application, too), as `ConditionVariable` is not available there.
- you need to wake *single* threads
- (my personal opinion) you're not needing the open phase of `ConditionVariable`, as a single call to `signalAll` is nicer to read than `open` directly followed by `close`.

while you should use `ConditionVariable` if

- you have phases within your application where you do not need any blocking at all

Answer (score 0):

Use Android `ConditionVariable` when its essentially a single use `block()`.

Use Java `Condition` when you have a loop that waits on `await()`

The reason is that there is no thread-safe way for the waiter to `block()` and then `close()` (without using additional synchronization mechanisms).

[See examples of `ConditionVariable` here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.os.ConditionVariable).

[See examples of `Condition` here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).